Make sub folder and move contents of folder into sub folder
I have many first level folders which contain variable layouts of files and sub folders. The first level folder names contain information I want to keep. For each folder I want

a first level folder with the original name
that has a subfolder called DATA
with the rest of the contents of the folder moved into the DATA subfolder

Visually,
<top_folder><BR>
    - <sub1><BR>
        - <file1>, etc<BR>

Becomes
<top_folder>
    - <DATA>
        - <sub1>
            - <file1>, etc


This batch file works except it becomes an infinite loop with the Move command.
for /D %%I in (*) do (
    set CurrDirName="%%~nxI"
    rename %CurrDirName% DATA
    md %CurrDirName%
    move DATA %CurrDirName%

)
I like DOS Move because it avoids waiting to copy data and then deleting. This could involved gigabytes of many files per top level folder. Can I avoid the infinite loop and still Move the folder?
